# Using SignalR.Client in Unity - The method or operation is not implemented

Tags: unity-game-engine, signalr, augmented-reality, .net-standard, signalr.client

I want to use SignalR in a UWP project on the HoloLens 2 and my application is partially running (one way works, one not).

#### The way it doesn't work

It does not run, when I have HTTPS-Redirection on my .Net-6-Web-API Server enabled and try to ignore it via the `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` line on unity side.

.Net 6-Project:

- `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` is active

Unity:

```
private void Start()
{
    _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl("http://192.168.178.41:5266/Signaler", (opts) =>
    {
        opts.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = (message) =>
        {
             // bypass SSL certificate
             if (message is HttpClientHandler clientHandler)
             {
                  clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
             }
            return message;
     };})
     .WithAutomaticReconnect()
     .Build();

     Connect();
}

private async Task Connect()
{
   _hubConnection.On<string>("SomeKey", (key) =>
   {
       Debug.Log($"New Key: {key}");
   });

   try
   {
       await _hubConnection.StartAsync(tokenSource.Token);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   { ... }
}
```

**The error (shorted text) I get:**

```
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
  at XXXXX.Network.MySignalRClient+<>c.<Start>b__1_1 (System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler message) [0x0000a] in D:\Repositories\XXXXX\Unity\XXXXX\Assets\Scripts\NetworkClients\MySignalRClient.cs:31 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.CreateHttpClient () [0x00118] in <d4f814eb48994df3870fe7c8338cc73a>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection..ctor (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionOptions httpConnectionOptions, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) [0x0009f] in <d4f814eb48994df3870fe7c8338cc73a>:0
```

The mentioned line 31 is the line with the `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback`.

#### How does the application work?

If I  disable the HTTPS-Redirection and remove the lines with the callback:

```
_hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl("http://192.168.178.41:5266/Signaler")
    .WithAutomaticReconnect()
    .Build();
```

#### Expected Behavior

HTTPS redirection should not be disabled extra on the server side, but the line with the callback on unity side should be enough.

#### SignalR Version

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.7.0.0 and all needed referenced Libraries for .Net Standard 2.0

#### Anything else?

**Typical Setup:**

[image: grafik]

Some DLLs are missing in the screenshot, because they are already included by other plugins that I use in Unity. The following packages are not shown: `System.Buffers, System.Memory, System.Numerics.Vectors, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe`

**Another project:**

I also created another empty .Net-6-Project in Visual Studio  with  Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.7.0.0 to check if I can connect, trigger the hub and get notified by the hub. There I use exactly the same lines to bypass the ssl certification and it works. So I guess there is something wrong with the .Net Standard 2.0 DLLs?